# Escaping special characters in Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match a regular expression in Perl. My code looks like the following:

```
my $source = "Hello_[version]; Goodbye_[version]";
my $pattern = "Hello_[version]";
if ($source =~ m/$pattern/) {
  print "Match found!"
}
```

The problem arises in that brackets indicate a character class (or so I read) when Perl tries to match the regex, and the match ends up failing. I know that I can escape the brackets with `\[` or `\]`, but that would require another block of code to go through the string and search for the brackets. Is there a way to have the brackets automatically ignored without escaping them individually?

Quick note: I can't just add the backslash, as this is just an example. In my real code, `$source` and `$pattern` are both coming from outside the Perl code (either URIEncoded or from a file).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using the Wrong Tool for the job.

You do not have a pattern! There are NO regex
characters in $pattern!

You have a literal string.

index() is for working with literal strings...

```
my $source = "Hello_[version]; Goodbye_[version]";
my $pattern = "Hello_[version]";
if ( index($source, $pattern) != -1 ) {
    print "Match found!";
}
```

Comment: What exactly is a "regex character"? I was under the impression that a regex is just a means of matching strings or patterns in strings, not a specific set of characters, unless there's another meaning to it that I'm not aware of?

Though, thanks for index(). I'll give that a shot when I'm at my server tomorrow; I do think that index() will work better and be cleaner than regex matching.

Comment: "regex character" was a typo, I meant to write "regex metacharacter".

Comment: Does not work when looking up a string with an @ sign in $source tough.

Answer (score 14):

`\Q` will disable metacharacters until `\E` is found or the end of the pattern.

```
my $source = "Hello_[version]; Goodbye_[version]";
my $pattern = "Hello_[version]";
if ($source =~ m/\Q$pattern/) {
  print "Match found!"
}
```

http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/perl/Findex.htm

Comment: Changed my "accepted answer", sorry, but while yours worked fine, I think `index()` was really what I was looking for. Thanks though!

Answer (score 13):

Use [quotemeta()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html):

```
my $source = "Hello_[version]; Goodbye_[version]";
my $pattern = quotemeta("Hello_[version]");
if ($source =~ m/$pattern/) {
  print "Match found!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape set of special characters in an expression by using the following command.

```perl
expression1 = 'text with special characters like $ % ( )';

expression1 =~s/[\?\*\+\^\$\[\]\\\(\)\{\}\|\-]/"\\$&"/eg ;

#This will escape all the special characters
print "expression1'; # text with special characters like \$ \% \( \)
```